# Displaying list of reports (SSRS) on the web site according to the AD login

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I’ve created groups with the relevant access properties to the reports through the AD account. What I want to do is to dynamically display on the html static website the list of reports according to the owners group. Eg. Group A has access to the reports no 1,2,3. Group B has access to reports no 4,5,6 and when the member of group A login through the AD on the website is able to see only list contains only 1,2,3 reports. How to do this?

Regards

Comment: Are you only using SSRS's web interface or is this part of some ASP.NET web site that uses reports? (or something else)

Comment: Well, this is default, static .html site, set up in IIS with the list of links to the SSRS reports. In order to see this page you have to login. The idea is to display different content (different list of links) respectively to the SSRS properties.

Comment: You call this a static website a couple of times, but you want to put dynamic content on the site. You will need to use some sort of server side language to accomplish this. The answers for this will vary dramatically depending on what technologies you want to use. If the web page remains as simple static HTML, you will not be able to meet your requirement.